# Unable to install 'SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid'

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am trying install 'SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid' into my xamarin portable project, facing some issues..

```
     \PocketExamFunda\packages'
     Install-Package : Could not install package 'SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid 2.5.1'. You are trying to install this package 
     into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly 
     references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
     At line:1 char:1
     + Install-Package SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid -Version 2.5.1
     + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

I didn't understand what is the issue, please any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The package you are trying to install is deprecated.
For the PCL project, you need to install the `SQLite.Net-PCL`.
The `SQLite.Net-PCL` is the package that you can use in `Xamarin.Android`, `Xamarin.iOS` and PCL projects:

Download from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/).

Comment: is it SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndriod is exists now? @Avi K.

Comment: From what I understand, the SQLite.Net-PCL contains the different implementations, including the Android one but there isn't a standalone SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid package anymore. You need to install the SQLite.Net-PCL package in each type of project you need the sqlite functionality in.

Comment: what would be the solution to connect sqlite on specific platform?

Comment: Install the SQLite.Net-PCL package on that platform - it will automatically install the right implementation for the chosen platform.

Comment: new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection('', dbPath); how we can we give arguments for this ? as platform attribute is not more in latest versions

Comment: var conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid(), dbPath);

Comment: but there is no 'SQLite.Net.Platform' exists.. can you please verify yourself.. for SQLite.Net-PCL 3.1.1 . please verify once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115006/discussion-between-dot-net-developer-and-avi-k).